# What does virtual display do with Image pixels when smaller display dimensions are set than the grabbed ones?

Tags: screen

I dont undestand what happens with pixels in Virtual Display in Android when output dimensions are reduced compared to the input ones ?

When I have for example input = size of my Display = 1920x960 and I set outputs to be 1920/3 and 960/3, what happens in that case with image pixels:

- pixel density is increased or
- maybe it takes only smaller part of screen that is centered and has
  dimensions 640x320 or
- something else?

Additionally, is there a way that I can only grab center part of screen as in picture below?

[image: Desired region to grab pixels from]

Comment: Is your question about developing an app that performs what you describe or do you want to capture the display content e.g. via adb?

Comment: Im working on app that uses this feature. It should control LEDs based on pixel RGB values only from the middle part of the screen.

Comment: Sorry but app development questions have to be asked on stackoverflow.com. This site is for questions from user perspective only.

Comment: Note: since the OP had already [asked the same question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72951933/2821954) (but was then suggested to ask on Super User, which ended up being migrated to here), I decided to leave this open, *with the caveat that the answers should focus on end-users POV*. For development-related solutions, please continue on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @srbms23 The you are redirected from site to site just shows that you question was not formulated in a away so that the users could understand it. In general when asking a development question you should always include your existing code or at least reference a code function you want to use.

Comment: @Robert Did everything as you described, added parts of code, didnt get an answer... so I tried with more concrete questions where I just ask the things that confuse me. The idea of this question was to get an explanation what Virtual Display does and that could lead to the solution of my main question. Additional part is just there to ask for alternatives if some exist.